# Java Code for Project Euler #12

Tags: java

I'm working on Problem #12 for Project Euler, which goes as follows:

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1
>
> 3: 1,3
>
> 6: 1,2,3,6
>
> 10: 1,2,5,10
>
> 15: 1,3,5,15
>
> 21: 1,3,7,21
>
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

This is the code I have so far, but the console does not return anything when it runs:

```
public class Euler12 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        int x = 2;
        boolean found = false;
        while (!found) {
            if (divisors(i) > 500) {
                System.out.println(i);
                found = true;
            }
            else {
                i +=x;
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int divisors (int n) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you print out every i and according divisors it's much simpler to track

Comment: Are you sure it just isn't slow and it is still running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running the program, it seems as though it has an extremely long run time, and looking at your algorithm, it does (I have done this problem before). You need to optimize "divisors"

**SPOILER**

If you change for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) into for (int i = 1; i*i <= n; i++), it will drastically reduce execution time.

UPDATE:
After running without the change, no answer within 4 minutes, which goes against Project Euler's one minute rule. After change, gets answer in ten seconds. Enjoy :)

Comment: This does reduce the execution time but it does not give you the correct answer. If you use the above fix, you then need to account for the other "half" of each divisor. Increment counter by 2. (counter+=2;)

Comment: @Will.Beninger You only need to go up to the square root of the number, and then multiply it by two at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class EulerProb12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int fib=0, count =1, i=1, incr=0;

        while (incr<5){         
            fib=0;
            while (i<=count){       
                fib = fib+i;
                i++;
            }

             i=1;
            incr=0;
            count++;

            for(int j=1; j<= Math.sqrt(fib); j++ ) // I used fib/2 here n result came late.
            {
                if(fib%j==0)
                {
                    incr++;
                }
            }
            incr*=2; // New logic when implemented along with sqrt
//          if(incr>150)
            System.out.println("Number: " + fib + " | Total Divisors: " + incr);        }
        System.out.println("Number: " + fib + " | Total Divisors: " + incr);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 alternatives:

1) Iterate through all triangles and stop if the `currentSum` (a triangle number) has over `THRESHOLD` divisors

**Time: 1.79 seconds**.

```
public class P12 {

    final static int THRESHOLD = 500;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getTriangle());
    }

    public static long getTriangle() {
        int n = 1;
        long currentSum = 0;
        while (!hasOverXDivisors(currentSum, THRESHOLD)) {
            currentSum += n;
            n++;
        }
        return currentSum;
    }

    private static boolean hasOverXDivisors(long nr, int threshold) {
        if ( nr <= threshold ) {
            return false;
        }
        int divisors = 0;
        int i;
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(nr);
        for ( i = 1 ; i <= sqrt ; i++ ) {
            if ( nr % i == 0 ) {
                divisors+=2;           // E.g.: (2, n/2), (3, n/3)
            }
        }
        if ( sqrt*sqrt == nr ){        // it was counted twice
            divisors--;
        }
        if ( divisors > threshold ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

2) It is based on coprime numbers properties. The triangle number is equal to `n*(n+1)/2` where `n` and `n+1` are coprimes => `n` and `(n+1)/2` are coprimes or `n/2` and `n+1` are coprimes ( it depends if `n` is even or odd ). 
**Time: 61 ms**.

```
public class P12 {

    final static int THRESHOLD_DIVISORS = 500;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getTriangle(1));
    }

    public static long getTriangle(int n) {
        long numberOfDivisors = 0;
        long firstCoprime, secondCoprime;
        while (true) {
            if ( n % 2 == 0 ) {
                firstCoprime = getNumberOfDivisors(n/2);
                secondCoprime = getNumberOfDivisors(n+1);

            } else {
                firstCoprime = getNumberOfDivisors(n);
                secondCoprime = getNumberOfDivisors((n+1)/2);
            }           
            numberOfDivisors = firstCoprime * secondCoprime;
            if ( numberOfDivisors > THRESHOLD_DIVISORS ) {
                return n*(n+1)/2;
            }       
            n++;
        }
    }

    private static long getNumberOfDivisors(long nr) {
        int divisors = 0;
        int i;
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(nr);
        for ( i = 1 ; i <= sqrt ; i++ ) {
            if ( nr % i == 0 ) {
                divisors+=2;           // E.g.: (2, n/2), (3, n/3)
            }
        }
        if ( sqrt*sqrt == nr ){        // it was counted twice
            divisors--;
        }
        return divisors;
    }

}
```

I used an integer as argument for `getTriangle()` method to be easier to improve this method. You can decide to start from a value that is bigger than `1` for this particular case. In this case, you can reduce the time at least 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Using "prime factorization" will make your `divisor()` much faster and better.

Try the following function, `getNumberOfDivisors()`, instead of your `divisor()`.

```
public static long getNumberOfDivisors (long n) {
    int ret = 1;

    long factor = 2;
    while (factor <= n) {
        int temp = 1;
        while (n % factor == 0) {
            n /= factor;
            temp++;
        }
        ret *= temp;
        factor++;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The function works because of the following theorem:

If n = p<sub>1</sub><sup>e1</sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>e2</sup> ... p<sub>n</sub><sup>en</sup>, where n is an integer and p<sub>i</sub> : primes,

then,

# of positive divisors : (e<sub>1</sub> + 1) (e<sub>2</sub> + 1) ... (e<sub>n</sub> + 1)